# Will a L298N Control a Maxxair RV Fan with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: hardware, pwm

MaxxAir RV Exhaust fans are 12v DC motors with a 5 amp max draw. People have replaced the boards with these:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08JG3CD8F/ref=ewc_pr_img_2?smid=A2RFU0Q5Y99ZUG&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JG3CD8F)
and a manual switch to reverse the motor.

But I want to do this with a raspberry pi.

Comment: you should be asking **how to control an L298N with Raspberry Pi?** ... search `Raspberry Pi L298N`

Comment: Questions: 1) You cannot do this with a Pi alone - you will need additional external components (transistor/relay & misc) 2) Do you want/need the "reversing" feature?

Comment: Yeah, need to be able to reverse and vary the speed.